# My doctype code is not showing up?

Tags: html, css, doctype, kentico

I have two doctypes above my `<html>` tag and I still don't see it in my page source. I tried just using one of them but they still dont work. Here is the site URL http://nonudot.io-web.com/demo.aspx and the doc types I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Heres a link to a screenshot of the code http://nonudot.io-web.com/LCValleyADA/media/ProjectsContent/Capture.JPG
Thanks

Comment: Why did you put two up there? The `<!DOCTYPE html>` is sufficient. Can you show us the preprocessed code?

Comment: your screenshot is broken. (relative links dont work here.)

Comment: Ok I just added a working link to the image

Comment: your NEW screenshot is STILL broken. Please just use a screen grab and upload the JPG to StackOverflow.

Comment: Don't use `capture.aspx`... your screenshot should end in `jpg` or `png` or similar.

Comment: Sorry guys, it works now

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot doesn't look anything like the final output. Compare the following

[image]

with

[image]

Notice how the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />` doesn't exist in the second screen grab (my screen grab from your posted site)? That's most likely because your not using the same page... I'm assuming that you might not be using the correct `MASTERPAGE`, or something has gone awry with your masterpages.

Your style sheets don't match up either.